# Muktzeh as a means to encourage cessation of labor

Tags: halacha, shabbat, sources-mekorot, muktzeh

In his work on the laws of *shabas* called *Kalkalas Shabas* (at [the beginning of the 3rd chapter](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40155&st=&pgnum=22&hilite=)), the [author of *Tif'eres Yisra'el*](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%9C_%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%A4%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%A5) introduces the topic of *muktzeh* by saying that the reason the sages prohibited use of non-essential objects on *shabas* was

> כדי שיהא שביתת האדם ניכרת שהיא כמצות התורה למען ינוח, שיהא לבו פנוי לתורת ה' ביום שבת.
>
> so that a person's cessation would be recognizable as the Biblical commandment "so that one shall rest", such that his mind could be available for God's Tora on *shabas* day.

From the way he phrases the next few lines, his contention seems to be not just that this is *a* reason for the prohibition against moving *muktzeh* objects, but the *primary* reason therefor.

As opposed to the opinions of Ramba"m and Ra'ava"d, quoted further in the paragraph, which hold that *muktzeh* laws were instituted to prevent forbidden activities being done with the objects in question, the *Tif'eres Yisra'el* appears to believe they were meant to simply free up a person from quotidian busywork, which would detract from his learning/spirituality (or to *represent* such a freeing up).

Is there an earlier source for this explanation of the laws of *muktzeh* - stated as a primary reason or otherwise? It seems pretty extreme and is unsourced, unlike the other explanations he includes.

Answer (score 1):

The [Ramban](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/olam_hatanah/mefaresh.asp?book=3&perek=23&mefaresh=ramban) (Vaykira 24,24) gives a similar explanation based on Mechilta:

> **יהיה לכם שבתון -  שיהיה יום שביתה לנוח בו**. ואמרו רבותינו (שבת כד ב
>   שבתון עשה הוא. והנה העושה מלאכה בי"ט עובר בלאו ועשה, והשובת בו מקיים
>   עשה. ועל דעתם, המועדות כולם הוקשו זה לזה, כי לא נאמר שבתון בחג המצות
>   ולא בעצרת.
>
> ובמכילתא (בא ט): ראיתי בפרשת החדש:  ושמרתם את היום הזה (שמות יב יז):
>   למה נאמר, והלא כבר נאמר כל מלאכה לא יעשה בהם (שם פסוק טז), אין לי אלא
>   דברים שהן משום מלאכה, דברים שהן משום שבות מנין?  תלמוד לומר: ושמרתם את
>   היום הזה להביא דברים שהן משום שבות.  יכול אף חולו של מועד יהא אסור
>   משום שבות, והדין נותן?  תלמוד לומר: ביום הראשון שבתון (להלן כט לט).
>
> **והנה ידרשו "שבתון" לשבות בו לגמרי אפילו מדברים שאינן מאבות מלאכות
>   ותולדותיהן.**
>
> אבל לא נתברר לי זה, שאם תאמר שהוא אסמכתא מה טעם שיאמרו בלשון הזה, כי
>   "שבות" בלשונם נאמר לעולם על של דבריהם, והאיך יתכן לומר דברים שהן
>   אסורין משום שבות של דבריהם מנין שיהו אסורין מן הכתוב, ודרך האסמכתות
>   לשנות שהם מן התורה לא שיאמרו דבר זה שהוא מדברי סופרים מנין מן התורה,
>   אבל היה לו לומר דברים שאינן מלאכה מנין תלמוד לומר שבתון.
>
> ונראה לי שהמדרש הזה לומר **שנצטווינו מן התורה להיות לנו מנוחה בי"ט** אפילו
>   מדברים שאינן מלאכה, לא שיטרח כל היום למדוד התבואות ולשקול הפירות
>   והמתנות ולמלא החביות יין, ולפנות הכלים וגם האבנים מבית לבית וממקום
>   למקום, ואם הייתה עיר מוקפת חומה ודלתות נעולות בלילה יהיו עומסים על
>   החמורים ואף יין וענבים ותאנים וכל משא יביאו בי"ט ויהיה השוק מלא לכל
>   מיקח וממכר, ותהיה החנות פתוחה והחנווני מקיף והשולחנים על שלחנם
>   והזהובים לפניהם, ויהיו הפועלים משכימין למלאכתן ומשכירין עצמם כחול
>   לדברים אלו וכיוצא בהן, והותרו הימים הטובים האלו ואפילו השבת עצמה שבכל
>   זה אין בהם משום מלאכה, **כך אמרה תורה "שבתון" שיהיה יום שביתה ומנוחה לא
>   יום טורח. וזהו פירוש טוב ויפה**.

Answer (score 1):

See [here](http://forum.bgu.co.il/index.php?showtopic=51743). The Author of this response to a student's question seems to be Rabbi Gil.

The earliest source brought there is Nechemiah.

(א) המקור הראשוני לאיסור מוקצה הוא הנאמר בכתובים (נחמיה פרק יג ):

(יד)זָכְרָה לִּי אֱלֹהַי עַל זֹאת וְאַל תֶּמַח חֲסָדַי אֲשֶׁר עָשִׂיתִי בְּבֵית אֱלֹהַי וּבְמִשְׁמָרָיו:
(טו)בַּיָּמִים הָהֵמָּה רָאִיתִי בִיהוּדָה דֹרְכִים גִּתּוֹת בַּשַּׁבָּת וּמְבִיאִים הָעֲרֵמוֹת
ועֹמְסִים עַל הַחֲמֹרִים וְאַף יַיִן עֲנָבִים וּתְאֵנִים וְכָל מַשָּׂא וּמְבִיאִים יְרוּשָׁלִַם בְּיוֹם הַשַּׁבָּת וָאָעִיד בְּיוֹם מִכְרָם צָיִד: (טז)וְהַצֹּרִים יָשְׁבוּ בָהּ מְבִיאִים דָּאג וְכָל מֶכֶר וּמֹכְרִים בַּשַּׁבָּת לִבְנֵי יְהוּדָה וּבִירוּשָׁלִָם:
(יז)וָאָרִיבָה אֵת חֹרֵי יְהוּדָה וָאֹמְרָה לָהֶם מָה הַדָּבָר הָרָע הַזֶּה אֲשֶׁר אַתֶּם עֹשִׂים וּמְחַלְּלִים אֶת יוֹם הַשַּׁבָּת: (יח)הֲלוֹא כֹה עָשׂוּ אֲבֹתֵיכֶם וַיָּבֵא אֱלֹהֵינוּ עָלֵינוּ אֵת כָּל הָרָעָה הַזֹּאת
וְעַל הָעִיר הַזֹּאת וְאַתֶּם מוֹסִיפִים חָרוֹן עַל יִשְׂרָאֵל לְחַלֵּל אֶת הַשַּׁבָּת:
(יט)וַיְהִי כַּאֲשֶׁר צָלֲלוּ שַׁעֲרֵי יְרוּשָׁלִַם לִפְנֵי הַשַּׁבָּת וָאֹמְרָה וַיִּסָּגְרוּ הַדְּלָתוֹת וָאֹמְרָה אֲשֶׁר לֹא יִפְתָּחוּם עַד אַחַר הַשַּׁבָּת וּמִנְּעָרַי הֶעֱמַדְתִּי עַל הַשְּׁעָרִים לֹא יָבוֹא מַשָּׂא בְּיוֹם הַשַּׁבָּת: (כ)וַיָּלִינוּ הָרֹכְלִים וּמֹכְרֵי כָל מִמְכָּר מִחוּץ לִירוּשָׁלִָם פַּעַם וּשְׁתָּיִם: (כא)וָאָעִידָה בָהֶם וָאֹמְרָה אֲלֵיהֶם מַדּוּעַ אַתֶּם לֵנִים נֶגֶד הַחוֹמָה אִם תִּשְׁנוּ יָד אֶשְׁלַח בָּכֶם מִן הָעֵת הַהִיא לֹא בָאוּ בַּשַּׁבָּת:

and this is interpreted by the Shulchan Oruch Horav,

וכך הובאו הדברים בשולחן ערוך הרב, או"ח סי' ש"ח סעיף ט"ז:
בימי נחמיה בן חכליה שהיו העם מזלזלים באיסור שבת,
כמ"ש בימים ההם ראיתי ביהודה דורכים גתות בשבת ומביאים הערימות וגו' 
**עשו חכמים סיג וגדר לאיסור הוצאה, וגזרו על כל הכלים אע"פ שמלאכתם להיתר**,
**שלא לטלטלם כלל אפילו לצורך תשמישן המיוחד להם, חוץ מן כוסות וקערות וסכין,**
וכיוצא בהם מהכלים הצריכים ביותר לסעודת השבת. 
**ואח"כ** כשראו חכמים שחזרו העם להזהר קצת באיסור שבת.
**חזרו והתירו לטלטל כל כלי שמלאכתו להיתר לצורך גופו או לצורך מקומו**. 
**ואח"כ כשראו שחזרו העם להזהר יותר חזרו והתירו לטלטל כל כלי שמלאכתו להיתר**,
**אפילו לצורך הכלי עצמו**. אבל לטלטל שלא לצורך כלל עדיין לא נמנו עליו חכמים להתירו,
ונשאר עומד באיסורו שנאסר בגזרת חכמים שבימי נחמיה בן חכליה.

Comment: The problem being prevented appears to be in Nechemya, and is clearly according to the Rebbe, that of _m'lacha_, as the latter says in the first bold part: עשו חכמים סיג וגדר לאיסור הוצאה. This is one of the additional explanations brought by the _Tif'eres Yisra'el_ but it is not the one about which I am asking.

Comment: . . . Although the Ramba"n's comment in @Yoni's answer would appear to be allusions to some of those _p'sukim_ in N'chemya.

Comment: However, now that you pointed me towards the Shulchan Aruch Harav, in the first _s'if_ of the section you quoted he formulates the reasons for the _isur_ in a remarkably similar way to that of the _Tif'eres Yisra'el_. The former preceded the latter by about a generation but I have no idea exactly when they wrote their respective works. . . Interesting.